# How to make my layout Textview auto adjust according to All AVDs

Tags: android, android-layout

now whats happening is the TextView of my layout does not adjust to higher AVDs like 10.1 or more..
now i want my TextView to auto adjust on every screen i.e. to run on every AVD..

please guide me how to do this

```
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">  


   <TextView 
    android:text="this is my First screen"
    android:layout_height="38dp" android:layout_weight="0.05" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
   <Button android:text="NEXT" android:id="@+id/next" android:layout_width="264dp" android:layout_height="34dp"></Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: TextView of my layout does not adjust to higher AVDs like 10.1 ? means? for textview's height or width?

Comment: the height and the size of text....i want that my text to auto adjust when running on high resolution screens i.e with size and height but its not happening while running on higher AVDs....the text becomes very small and is very difficult to read.

Comment: android:layout_height="38dp" for textview is very small for high resolution device. I think you should change this by   android:layout_height="wrap_content" and then set textview's textsize like android:setTextsize="14dp" set this an try again. Thanks

Comment: the real problem is that my text should automatically adjust to every screen resolution..assigning some text size won't do because if we assign some text size it won't be able to optimize when run on new screen either higher or lower.

Comment: but if you don't assign the textsize should you know what the text size it has by default?

Comment: what i can do is to assign the textview in proportion with the screen dimensions..

Answer (score 2):

simply replace this

android:layout_height="38dp"

with

wrap_content,

Comment: thanx for replying but this thing does not work while going to AVD 3.7 and above , the text becomes so small that it can't be read.

Comment: there is another size to be used, i m not remembering the name now,, fill_parent, wrap_content, 3rd 1, did u try 3rd 1,? i think thats wrap_parent available for higher apis

Comment: i have tried everything moreover as i searched it cant be done this way..there is some class you have to make to adjust your text view for every screen

Comment: u can search "how to get window size," then programetically check for higher Api window size and fix textSize of textView using java class."